# Proof that $\bf M$-$\bf Set$ is a cartesian closed category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}$ be the category of the sets equipped with a right action of a monoid $M$; fixed an $M$-$\mathrm {Set}$ (call it $X$), I want to prove that the functor $-\times X: \mathbf {M\text{-} Set}\to\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}$ is a left adjoint to $-^X$ (so  I also have to prove that the last functor is defined $\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}\to\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}$).

Using the adjunction $F\dashv U:\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}\to\bf Set$, where $U$  is  the  forgetful  functor, for any $Y$ in $\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}$  I  have  that $$U(Y^X)\cong \mathbf{Set}(*,U(Y^X))\cong \mathbf {M\text{-} Set}(M,Y^X),$$ because $F(*)$ is $M$. In this way I described the underlying set of $Y^X$; easily, it becomes an $M$-$\mathrm {Set}$ with the action that sends the morphism $f:M\to Y^X$ to the morphism $m\cdot f$ such that $(m\cdot f) (1_M)=f(m)$. At this point I can prove the adjunction showing that  the counit  is the evaluation and it has the universal property needed (in class we did the same thing to prove that $-\times S$ is a left adjoint to $-^S$ in $\bf Set$). Is my reasoning correct? I'm confused because the teacher mentioned (during the proof) that $\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}(M,Y^X)$ is in natural  bijecton with $\mathbf {M\text{-} Set}(M\times X,Y)$, but this should be a consequence of our thesis. I quite can't tell  if he was just mentioning it, or if this bijection must be used in the proof (as a necessary condition for the thesis to be true), because he left the rest as exercise.

Comment: Your approach doesn't at all describe the underlying set of $Y^X$; if you don't know what $Y^X$ is in the first place, talking about morphisms $M\to Y^X$ doesn't clarify anything. Your professor's comment is the key to getting rid of this circularity.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Should I say that if $Y^X$ is a right adjoint of the product, necessarily  $\mathbf {M\text{-}Set}(M,Y^X)\cong \mathbf {M\text{-}Set}(M\times X,Y)$? And then equip this last  set with an action of $M$ that makes it actually a right adjoint?

Comment: Yes, that would do the trick!

Comment: What is the relation to your older question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4185867 ?